# jQuery search not working with input type date?

Tags: jquery, filter

I am trying to use jQuery's search filter with my input type date but it's not working for me. It's working only for `input type=text`.

This is my markup and code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  alert(input);
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
  }
}
```

Markup:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" class="" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Year Turnover</th>
      <th>Receipt</th>
      <th>Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="gradeA" id="myUL">
      <td>
        <?php echo $data['company_analytics']['last_year_turnorder'];?>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <?php echo $receipt;?>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <?php echo $data['company_analytics']['period'];?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting dynamic data from database in table format. Now I want to add filter on that table on `period` column. So that I used above code but it's not working for me. I think I am using datepicker in search box that's why its not getting data. Is there any way to show data from table with search box with datepicker.

I refer this link to get data. But in my condition data is dynamic and coming in table format.

[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list)

Comment: Also none of your javascript is using `jQuery`

Comment: Straight javascript is a very difficult way of doing things.  The library JQuery or others can be included to simplify tasks like this.  This is a good reference on jQuery https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: It's impossible for us to help without knowing what data we're working with. The link you posted doesn't have date data in it, but you clearly that's the part where you're struggling. At this point all I can recommend is that you console.log or alert each step of the way so you can see where you're going wrong. a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; for example won't find anything given the html you've provided.